# Incompatibilidad de datos

Tags: java

Recien inicio en java, quisiera saber al recibir por consola un **int**, **float** o **double**  y por error el usuario digita un **char** o **String**, como evito ese error.

Comment: ¿Y lo que has probado hasta ahora dónde está? Postea tu código actual para partir de ahí.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes te invito a que realices el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Debes revisar [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Coloca el código que tienes, puedes editar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

```
double d=Double.parseDouble(valorRecibidoDeConsola)
```

y ya podrás operar con el como si fuera un número. También se puede hacer para ints y otro tipo de datos, pero si lo que quieres es operar con ellos, utiliza Double. Son números con decimales que si los pasases a entero los perderías.